# Add a link to a specific word on your website

Tags: html

On my website I have a paragraph of information where I want a link to a specific word rather than "click here [web url]"

A good example of what I want is on Kotaku http://www.kotaku.co.uk/2015/01/09/third-party-gamecube-adapters-available-wii-u the pink text are links to other websites.

**When I attempt to do it, it does this**

[image: ahref link]

It goes onto a separate line, different colour text and position which is odd, the link works though. The code I have is this

```
<p><a href="http://gmazzocato.altervista.org/colorwheel/wheel.php">Gmazzocato</a> is a colour wheel etc... </p>
```

Comment: I think you have somewhere a css that affects the `a`. It should work fine

Comment: Takeaway the `<p>` tags: http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_p.asp

Comment: seems to work as it should... there are perhaps other elements on your site that are messing it up.

Comment: @DanielStanley http://w3fools.com

Comment: @MelanciaUK A quote from w3fools.com "For many **beginners**, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a **decent learning experience**". I have seen the website before and linking to that provides nothing constructive. For this simple question `w3schools` probably would be beneficial to the OP..

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need??

```css
 a{text-decoration: none;color: #cc00cc}
            a:hover{text-decoration: underline;color: #990099}
```

```html
<p><a href="http://gmazzocato.altervista.org/colorwheel/wheel.php">Gmazzocato</a> is a colour wheel etc... </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. My navigation bar was linking to  so whenever I used this tag, it would collide to others. I put my navbar into a class and linked it, thanks to those who helped anyway.